# OkHttp SSLHandshakeException SSL handshake aborted Failure in SSL library, a protocol error

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

```
04-23 17:17:38.434 21599-21956/ D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x0 NativeCrypto_SSL_interrupt
04-23 17:17:38.435 21599-21956/ D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x635d8808: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:744 0x5e6c46fd:0x00000000)
```

Android lower version devices (4.1 - 4.4) gives SSL error. Previously was working fine with following versions :

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.9.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.3.0'
```

But after upgrading these libraries things change. Every service call gives SSL handshake exception.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.4.0'
```

Also if i downgrade these libraries to previous version it still doesnt work. But git checkout to the previous commit works fine. Clueless.

Comment: Did you add certificate in keystore ?

Comment: @Lucifer i think i didn't. Which certificate are you referring to ?

Comment: you are using SSL, so there should a security certificate at server side.

Comment: Server is not even getting called. The services are getting blocked on android side

Comment: are you behind proxy ?

Comment: No i am not. if i checkout to the commit previous to the version upgrade, it works fine.

Comment: Have edited the solution in my question. Thanks anyways. Have added reference. It happened because OKHTTP3 removed some protocols in the upgraded library. Will have to add it by explicitely.

Comment: You should add it as answer rather than updating your question. This way it will help future visiters.

Comment: Add the concrete error message/stacktrace to your question.

Comment: @Lucifer how to add it as answer ? i am new here

Comment: @Robert Updated whatever error i got in stacktrace in the question

Comment: The client seems to send an SSLv3 request which is not accepted by the server. Modern server only accept TLSv1.x requests. SSLv3 is dead.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So I solved it by adding the following to my http client object

```
 ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS)
            .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2, TlsVersion.TLS_1_1, TlsVersion.TLS_1_0)
            .cipherSuites(
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA)
            .build();

httpClient.connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec))
```

reference : https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3894

Comment: but how to use that solution with certificate pinning

Comment: I am having the "CLEARTEXT communication not enabled for client", but already have the solution for it on newer android versions.

Comment: To know which TLS versions and Cipher suites are supported by your server, first analyse by any SSL Analyzer (i.e. https://sslanalyzer.comodoca.com) then update your ConnectionSpec code accordingly.

Comment: I have this problem on AppGlideModule that can not download images with this error:  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this issue when upgrading to OkHttp 4.x. Rather than having to keep track of all known TLS versions and all known ciphers as [Anker recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49981435/920849), use OkHttp's [allEnabledTlsVersions](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-connection-spec/-builder/all-enabled-tls-versions/) and [allEnabledCipherSuites](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-connection-spec/-builder/all-enabled-cipher-suites/) methods:

```
val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
…
// The default OkHttp configuration does not support older versions of TLS,
// or all cipher suites.  Make our support as reasonably broad as possible.
builder.connectionSpecs(listOf(ConnectionSpec.CLEARTEXT,
    ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
        .allEnabledTlsVersions()
        .allEnabledCipherSuites()
        .build()))
…
val okHttpClient = builder.build()
```

These lists will stay current as long as you upgrade OkHttp regularly.  From the [ConnectionSpec API doc](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-connection-spec/):

> Use Builder.allEnabledTlsVersions and Builder.allEnabledCipherSuites
>   to defer all feature selection to the underlying SSL socket.
>
> The configuration of each spec changes with each OkHttp release. This
>   is annoying: upgrading your OkHttp library can break connectivity to
>   certain web servers! But it’s a necessary annoyance because the TLS
>   ecosystem is dynamic and staying up to date is necessary to stay
>   secure. See OkHttp’s TLS Configuration History to track these changes.