# SSLHandshakeException when running Apache Beam Pipeline in Dataflow

Tags: java, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have an Apache Beam Pipeline. In one of the DoFn steps it does an https call (think REST API). All this works fine with DirectRun in my local environment.

This is my local environment, apache beam 2.16.0:

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.1 (d66c9c0b3152b2e69ee9bac180bb8fcc8e6af555; 2019-04-04T12:00:29-07:00)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.6.1
Java version: 1.8.0_222, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.0.0-1025-gcp", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

However, when I deploy to Dataflow everything works fine except that the https calls fail with the stack trace shown below.

Any suggestion on how to troubleshoot and overcome this issue?

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2033)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1135)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:351)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:310)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:178)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:236)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:109)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:77)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange$okhttp(Transmitter.kt:162)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:35)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:82)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:84)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:71)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.kt:184)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:66)
...
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:218)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:183)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:335)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:280)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:252)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:74)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:576)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:564)
...
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:218)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:183)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:335)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:280)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:252)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:74)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:576)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:564)
...
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:218)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:183)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:335)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:280)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:252)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:74)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:576)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:564)
...
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:218)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:183)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:335)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:280)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:252)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:74)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:576)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.output(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:71)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:139)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:218)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:183)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:335)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:201)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1316)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:149)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1049)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
timestamp   
2019-12-01T18:11:22.370Z
logger  

severity    
WARNING
worker  

step    

thread  
524
```

I followed the directions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49980508/okhttp-sslhandshakeexception-ssl-handshake-aborted-failure-in-ssl-library-a-pro) and limited the CipherSuites to the following:

```
ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS)
        .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_3, TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
        .cipherSuites(
                CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384)
        .build();

    httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder() 
        .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec))
        .build();
```

Again it works fine with DirectRun, when submitted to DataFlow the error now is a bit more specific:

```
java.net.UnknownServiceException: Unable to find acceptable protocols. isFallback=false, modes=[ConnectionSpec(cipherSuites=[TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384], tlsVersions=[TLS_1_3, TLS_1_2], supportsTlsExtensions=true)], supported protocols=[TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectionSpecSelector.configureSecureSocket(ConnectionSpecSelector.kt:63)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:345)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:310)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:178)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:236)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:77)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange$okhttp(Transmitter.kt:162)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:35)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:82)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:84)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:71)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.kt:184)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:66)
    ...
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:218)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:183)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:335)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:280)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:252)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:74)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:576)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:564)
    ...
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:218)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:183)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:335)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:280)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:252)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:74)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:576)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:564)
    ...
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:218)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:183)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:335)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:280)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:252)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:74)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:576)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:564)
    ...
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:218)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:183)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:335)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:280)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:252)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:74)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:576)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.output(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:71)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:139)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:218)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:183)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:335)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:201)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1316)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:149)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1049)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Server SSL Report:

[image]

Comment: I did some searching on this error, and found this reference: https://dzone.com/articles/troubleshooting-javaxnetsslsslhandshakeexception-r . It looks like you are making the HTTP calls in a custom ParDo, correct? Can you access the server its contacting and determine the cipher suites supported. Since it works locally on direct runner, but not on the GCE vms used by DataflowRunner, I am guessing the separate clients in these cases support separate cipher suites. And when run on dataflow runner VMs, that client does not have a common cipher suite that both the server and client support.

Comment: @AlexAmato yes it runs inside a ParDo handler. The TLS version and protocol I added in the original post are examples of the ones supported by the server. BTW, directRun also runs on a GCE VM I use for dev. purposes.

I just added the relevant part of the server Qualys SSL Report

Comment: I see that your server supports your client side specified TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384. Though, perhaps the error you saw after specifying that meant that the client was unable to support the protocols specified. I am not sure how to diagnose further, if you can ssh into the vm that dataflow spins up and determine the same information, that might work. But dataflow may teardown the VMs on you, which would make it difficult. It might be easier to try a different http client library first as well. You are using okhttp3?

Comment: Perhaps try https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client

Its pulled in as a dep in one of the beam extension folders.
https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/2acbfbd23a23ee6eed77cbe74690f66f985c9815/sdks/java/extensions/google-cloud-platform-core/build.gradle#L47

Comment: @AlexAmato switched to google-http-java-client and the problem went away... I will go with this work around, thanks!!

Comment: Thanks, too bad we couldn't get to the root of the issue. But glad this was a helpful work around. :)

Comment: I've joined late to the party. I have faced the same exact problem in equivalent environments. In DirectRunner works ok, but on Dataflow runner throws the `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure`. I've implemented the google-http-java-client but the problem is the same. Do you have any other piece of advice in order to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**

Since Beam 2.14, you can create an implementation of a JvmInitializer that will run on JVM instantiation. Implement and register one to override google's security settings.

```
@AutoService(value = JvmInitializer.class)
public class MyJvmInitializer implements JvmInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup() {
        Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms", "");
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeProcessing(PipelineOptions options) {}
}
```

To register the above I use [AutoService](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.auto.service/auto-service/1.0), you can register it differently if you prefer.

**Explanation**

From the strong algorithms for ciphers, only GCM is supported in Java, CHACHA20_POLY1305 is not supported yet. In your local/DirectRunner, the JVM is instantiated with the default settings, which include the GCM algos. So it can use `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` or `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` which are both supported by the server.

Google Dataflow, on the other hand, passes a property file with security settings to the worker JVM. The property file is in the worker VM in `/opt/google/dataflow/tls/disable_gcm.properties`.

These properties explicitly disable GSM algos. The content of the file is

```
# We disable GCM explicitly, since Java 8 has a naive and
# impractically slow implementation of it.
#
# SSLv3 is disabled in JDK by default due to POODLE vulnerability.
# See CVE-2014-3566 for more details.
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, GCM

# /dev/random blocks in virtualized environments due to lack of
# good entropy sources, which makes SecureRandom use impractical.
# In particular, that affects the performance of HTTPS that relies
# on SecureRandom.## Due to that, /dev/urandom is used as the default.
#
# See http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/ for some background
# on security of /dev/urandom on Linux.
securerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom"
```

So, there are no common ciphers between an HTTP client in the Dataflow workers and the server you are trying to reach.

Comment: I have a different problem, but one which still requires using a JvmInitializer.  You say, "you can register it differently if you prefer".  How would one go about doing this manually?

Comment: @SourceSimian you will need to create a provider conf file in the path `META-INF/services/org.apache.beam.sdk.harness.JvmInitializer ` and include it in your jar. The content of the file will be `com.mypackage.MyJvmInitializer`. Check https://www.baeldung.com/java-spi for an intro to Java SPI