# How to call external API from Google Cloud Function in Java using Android Library

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that is triggered by pub/sub topic. Now when the function gets called I want to put message data to my server using rest API. I am using 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4' dependency to call API. my function deploys successfully but when it triggers it will show the following error.

```
Failed to execute com.example.Example
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/os/Handler
    at com.example.Example.callapi(Example.java:44)
    at com.example.Example.accept(Example.java:25)
    at com.example.Example.accept(Example.java:15)
    at com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.BackgroundFunctionExecutor$TypedFunctionExecutor.serviceLegacyEvent(BackgroundFunctionExecutor.java:285)
    at com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.BackgroundFunctionExecutor.lambda$serviceLegacyEvent$8(BackgroundFunctionExecutor.java:375)
    at com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.BackgroundFunctionExecutor.runWithContextClassLoader(BackgroundFunctionExecutor.java:382)
    at com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.BackgroundFunctionExecutor.serviceLegacyEvent(BackgroundFunctionExecutor.java:375)
    at com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.BackgroundFunctionExecutor.service(BackgroundFunctionExecutor.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1297)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.runner.Invoker$NotFoundHandler.handle(Invoker.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.os.Handler
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 37 more
```

**Cloud function java file--**

```
package com.example;

import com.example.Example.PubSubMessage;
import com.google.cloud.functions.BackgroundFunction;
import com.google.cloud.functions.Context;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

public class Example implements BackgroundFunction<PubSubMessage> {
  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Example.class.getName());

  @Override
  public void accept(PubSubMessage message, Context context) {
    String data = message.data != null
      ? new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(message.data))
      : "Hello, World";
    logger.info(data);

    callapi(data);
  }

  public static class PubSubMessage {
    String data;
    Map<String, String> attributes;
    String messageId;
    String publishTime;
  }
  

   public void callapi(String data) {
     
       
        RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();
        rp.add("data", data);

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.post("http://198.198.198.1/jhd/v1/jhd_controllers/addPurchase", rp, new JsonHttpResponseHandler());   
    }
}
```

**pom.xml file--**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>cloudfunctions</groupId>
  <artifactId>pubsub-function</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.loopj.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-async-http</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4</version>
    </dependency>

<!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
-->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.functions</groupId>
      <artifactId>functions-framework-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <!-- Required for Java 11 functions in the inline editor -->
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>.google/</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Why do you use android library?

Comment: if you want to access google cloud xxx function, there is very likely to have sdk for the language you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're using is an Android HTTP Client. It's not possible to use Android Libraries in Java Cloud Functions. As you can see in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/java-runtime#execution_environment), the entire execution environment is based on Ubuntu Image and Java 11. It doesn't include the Android environment.

Even if you look at the [system packages](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/system-packages) included by default, you won't be able to find the packages needed to run Android Libraries.

The solution is to use a Java HTTP Client, like the one that's already [built in](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) Java 11. You're also free to choose alternative libraries, as there are many HTTP clients available out there that supports both Java and Android.

Comment: Thanks, Dondi for your support. Now I'm using the library for java11 and the code executes perfectly but it gives  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure exception. Can you please help me for this issue?

Comment: @ViralRadadiya, it appears to be a new problem. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59381416/7031308) might help you get started. Once you have enough information, please create a new question to isolate the problem. For now, if I addressed your original concern, then consider accepting my answer.